# SharePoint User Profile Sync to AD

Tags: active-directory, user-profile

One question regarding the user profile sync, we are trying to sync user photo in SharePoint back to AD picture. We have one AD forest, two domains, and in SharePoint we have two Synchronization Connections respectly. And when setting up the property mapping for Export, you can only map the property once to one Synchronization Connection.
Does anyone come across the issue like this before?

Comment: Use a single synchronization connection per forest.

Comment: If changing from one connection to two connections, user profile in one domain will be removed and re-imported instead of updating. And profile data maintained in SharePoint will be lost.